# Working out a percentage by using CountRows in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to work out the percentage of a record set that I have against the total number of records in my dataset in and SSRS Report. I currently have the following

```
=Sum((IIf(Fields!MessagingSLA.Value = "NA", 1, 0), "Alarms")/ (CountRows("Alarms")) * 100, 0) & "%
```

I believe I have the syntax incorrect but cant seem to get it right. Could anyone assist me please?

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses are wrong - the closing parenthesis for your Sum operator is the last one in the expression.  Try the following:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!MessagingSLA.Value = "NA", 1, 0), "Alarms") / (CountRows("Alarms"))
```

... and format the result as a percentage in the text-box properties.